# Función javaScript en un a href

Tags: php, javascript

Quisiera saber la mejor forma de llamar a una función javascript en un href

lo he intentado de esta forma

```
<a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_logout_url() ); ?> " onclick="hola();return false;"><?php _e('Log Out'); ?> </a>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo no funciona lo que tienes? Poniendo el código que compartes (imaginando los datos de PHP), funciona sin problemas como se puede ver en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rptrj63/)

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor en mi humilde opinión es siempre evitar lo llamado Inline Javascript, es decir embedir código Javascript dentro de nuestros elementos de HTML, sino siempre hacerlo desde un tag de tipo `<script></script>` o mejor aún en un archivo JS completamente separado de nuestro HTML para así dar mucho mayor flexibilidad al la reutilización de nuestro código y mantenimiento del mismo sobre todo. Con esto dicho este ejemplo sería lo más básico para ejecutar un bloque de JS a través de un clic de un elemento HTML de tipo `<a></a>`

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.aLink').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert ("Hola Mundo");
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='google.com' class='aLink'>Google</a>
```

**Nota:** El motivo de usar `e.preventDefault()` es para evitar el redireccionamiento que hace el navegador al dar clic sobre una liga, de esta forma solo manda llamar la alerta sin que tu página cambie.

**Ejemplo sin jQuery:**

```js
document.getElementById('aLink').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert ("Hola Mundo");
});
```

```html
<a href='google.com' id='aLink'>Google</a>
```

Comment: El OP no sugiere el uso de jQuery, únicamente hace referencia a javascript.

Comment: Listo, ya agregué ejemplo sin jQuery

Comment: Me marca un error en la linea de .addEventListener('click',function(e){

Este es el error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: A tu elemento `<a>` le falta el atributo id: `<a href='' id='aLink'>...</a>`

Comment: Si, ya se lo puse

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Agregar un id a tu etiqueta

**HTML**

```
<a id="click"> <h1> Click me </h1> </a>
```

Y luego crear una funcion js que con el evento click

**JS**

```
$('#click').click(function (event)
{
    alert("Hola Mundo");
});
```

Claramente necesitarias la libreria jquery

Saludos

Comment: Si, claro ya importé la libreria, pero utilizando esa forma de llamar a la función, no funciona

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez que error te aparece?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGFCDBZE0PYI

Te dejo un ejemplo ams practico

Comment: con la forma que me pasaste, ninguno, solo que no se ejecuta la función

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez la funcion como tal seria el o evento, aunque si quieres puedes llamar la funcion desde este evento, 

tal vez así entiendas mejor
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGFCGZ4U0LH4

Comment: Ok, ya intente la forma, pero no se realiza la función, más bien se redirige a donde va el href.

Comment: Creo que lo que trata de explicar @AlejoFlorez es que puedes con este evento llamar una funcion que quieras, solo deberas llamarla directamente

A mi forma de ver es la opcion mas sencilla

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="link" href="javascript:hola();">texto</a>
```

buena forma:

```
<a id="link" href="#" onclick="hola();">texto</a>

<a id="link" href="#" onclick="hola();return false;">texto</a>

<a id="link" href="link.html" onclick="hola();return false;">texto</a>
```

**return false;** evita que el link siga el enlace del href.

Ejemplo con Jquery:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    hola();
    return false; 
});
```

Creo que esta es la mejor forma con jquery:

```
 $('#link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    hola(); 
});
```

Comment: Si tambien necesito que siga el href, solo tengo que quitar el preventDefault?